# How to best create breaks in a comment using PHP/MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried searching for this, but no luck. I have programmed a comment system using PHP and MYSQL and I am having problems displaying comments that users have breaked using enter. I currently have html blocked from all comments in order to submit a sanitized entry into MYSQL so they cannot use `<br>` or anything like that.

I guess my question is this: Are there any special techniques to allow more freedom in the comments users post, especially if they hit enter for a break?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `nl2br` for this. Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a

```
$input = str_replace("\n", "<br />", $input);
```

To manually put in the breaks before inputting to the database.  Just make sure this happens after any `strip_tags` or other validation.